# How can I hide a specific element that is outside of .each() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By Sharepoint a bunch of tds get generated with a few elements inside of them. So just to be clear I cant edit or change elements since it gets generated.

What I want to accomplish is to iterate throught all `'.js-contentFollowing-itemLink'` and then if the .text() contains the specific text I am looking for the `'<span> Stop following</span>'` should become hidden with `'.hide()'`.

I cant seem to accomplish this I have tried many ways.

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QXwyk/3/

Also take notice that I cant grab a id that is unique and many of these elements are generated with different values and texts.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="ms-contentFollowing-itemTitle">
<a href="#" class="js-contentFollowing-itemLink">test</a>
</span>

<br>
<div class="js-contentFollowing-itemUrlDiv">
<span class="ms-metadata ms-contentFollowing-itemUrl"></span>

    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ms-metadata ms-contentFollowing-itemUrl ms-contentFollowing-itemFullUrl" style="visibility: visible; border-color: transparent; background-color: transparent;">
</div>
<a href="#" class="ms-secondaryCommandLink"><span>Stop following</span></a>
```

My JS:

```
$('.js-contentFollowing-itemLink').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "test")

            $(this).closest("span").hide();


    });
```

Note: I know it hides wrong element but the If statement works its the code inside the if statement that I cant accomplish I need to hide ' Stop following'. This JS is just one of the examples I have done that is not working.

I tried with `$('.ms-secondaryCommandLink span').hide();` inside the if statement but that removed all `<span>` with "Stop following" :/

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="ms-content">
<span class="ms-contentFollowing-itemTitle">
<a href="#" class="js-contentFollowing-itemLink">test</a>
</span>

<br>
<div class="js-contentFollowing-itemUrlDiv" id="contentFollowingUrl_18" url="http://dev/socialsites/Utförsåkning">
<span class="ms-metadata ms-contentFollowing-itemUrl"></span>

    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ms-metadata ms-contentFollowing-itemUrl ms-contentFollowing-itemFullUrl" style="visibility: visible; border-color: transparent; background-color: transparent;">
</div>
<a href="#" class="ms-secondaryCommandLink"><span>Stop following</span></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.js-contentFollowing-itemLink').each(function () {
     if ($(this).text() == "test")
         var text = $(this).closest('.ms-content').find('.ms-secondaryCommandLink').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QXwyk/4/

Comment: aaah it was the .find() method I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Several issues in your code:

```
$('.js-contentFollowing-itemLink').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "test")
    var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide); <-- hide not closed properly
} <--- Extra bracket here..
});
```

Working code:

```
$('.js-contentFollowing-itemLink').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "test") {
        var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah my wrong it doesnt look like that in my VS sorry about that, I did a few changes to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can select the object containing  specific text by following way,based on which you can can do remaining actions ...

Example: $('.js-contentFollowing-itemLink:contains(test)').hide(); will hide "test"